# Is there any way to config calico support multiple VNI in vxlan mode?

Tags: calico, cni, vxlan

Is there any way to config calico support multiple VNI in vxlan mode?

I need multi-tenancy with Calico, but I can't find how to set multiple VNIs in the Calico configuration, how can we do that? Or is there any other CNI can provide this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a CNI that can do multi VXLAN-vni on pod side given that [Kubernetes](https://github.com/kubernetes/design-proposals-archive/blob/acc25e14ca83dfda4f66d8cb1f1b491f26e78ffe/network/networking.md?plain=1#L13-L15) expects the network to be flat.

If you want to establish muti-tenancy with Kubernetes, RBAC and network policy is the way to do it. [shift-left](https://www.tigera.io/blog/how-to-integrate-kubernetes-rbac-and-calico-to-achieve-shift-left-security/) might be something worth exploring.

Comment: Maybe it's true, we need to make a new multi-tenancy CNI plugin.